# Tableau calculating a percentage using a row as the base

Tags: tableau-api

I have calculated the median across all the L1 to L5, A to E. For each L(1 to 5), i want to use the median of C as the base of 100% and see how the other A, C, D,E match against it. How do i do it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u7cZ.png)

Comment: You should just subtract C from the other value and then divide by the other value: (B-C)/B

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this picture to see my values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0BkH.jpg)

[Look this picture to see how to set C depends upon Job Grade as a base, use the following computed field `Basis C (Job Grade)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dlxJ.jpg)

Create a computed field `Basis C (Job Grade)`:

```
{ FIXED [Job Grade]:
                    Max(
                        IF [Performance Grade]="C" 
                        THEN [Median Per grade/performance] 
                        ELSE 0 
                        END
                    )
}
```

FIXED level of detail expressions compute base C using the specified dimensions [Performance Grade], without reference to the dimensions in the view.

Then it is easy to compute `C as the base of 100%`:

```
[Median Per grade/performance]/[Basis C (Job Grade)]
```

[Look at this picture to see how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7UTy.jpg)

Or you need to compute `Base C` for all:

```
{ FIXED :
        Max(
            IF [Performance Grade]="C" 
            THEN [Median Per grade/performance] 
            ELSE 0 
            END
        )
}
```

FIXED level of detail expressions compute base C, without reference to the dimensions in the view.

Then it is easy to compute `C as the base of 100%`:

```
[Median Per grade/performance]/[Basis C]
```

[Look this picture to see how to set C as a base, use the following computed field `Basis C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHl2p.jpg)

[Look at my tableau solution for more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q3cy.jpg)